# Algorithm to merge contacts

Tags: algorithm, maps, graph-algorithm

I am working on a project which requires to find similar contact.

I/P : it's in the form

```
C1 -> abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com ... (could be any size)
C2 -> asdas@gmail.com
C2 -> friedzie@gmail.com,myfriend@yahoo.com
C4 -> brothers@yahoo.com,asdas@gmail.com
```

I want to group contacts like C2,C4 and merge them together because they share same email.

Comment: I see C2 and C4 have common addresses, but not C1 and C4.

Comment: @Arun thanks, I have edited my answer

Comment: could it happen that C1 and C2 are at the same group, but also C2 and C3 are in a different group (like: c1: [a@a.a], c2: [a@a.a, b@b.b], c3: [b@b.b])?

Answer (score 2):

Hash the Addresses to the contacts, and when you encounter an address that is already in the hashmap, that's a shared contact.

it is roughly `O(N)`

---

Edit:

in case there are more then two candidates with matching emails, they all are grouped.

e.g.

C1  A@gmail.com
C1  B@gmail.com
C2  A@gmail.com
C2  C@gmail.com
C3  B@gmail.com
C3  D@gmail.com

1st Pass:
A@gmail.com => C1
B@gmail.com => C1
+ A@gmail.com => C2 (ALREADY C1) => merge C1 -> C2
C@gmail.com => C2
B@gmail.com => C3 (Already C1) => Merge C1 -> C3
D@gmail.com => C3

now you know you need to merge: C2 into C1, and C3 into C1.

Comment: You could still have multiple emails shared across contacts
e.g.

abc@gmail.com -> C1,C2
xyz@gmail.com -> C4,C1 

I want to group the entire set.

Comment: @KunalBalani then C1 & C2 should be the same person, if he share abc@gmail.com,
and C4 should be added to that group of `same person`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to apply **Union Find** algorithm.

Merge the containers (i.e. union) whenever they have a common email address.

See: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf